# jQuery within AJAX not updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a webpage - lets call it index.php. Using AJAX I load content from another page after a dropdown selection - lets call this one catalog.php.

catalog.php has an empty DIV, that, using jQuery, gets some text from yet another page - this final one will be called data.php. It replaces the contents of the DIV, and refreshes every 1 second.

If I go directly to catalog.php (using the proper GET), the jQuery will run and the DIV will update every second as needed.

However, if I go to index.php - catalog.php will load and run, but the DIV remains empty, and it will not populate the DIV with data.php.

What's going on here?

Sample code from index.php:

```
<script>
    function showForm(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","catalog.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Sample code from catalog.php:

```
<div id="divstuff"></div>
<script src="jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(function(){
            $("#divstuff").load("data.php?data=somedata");
}, 1000);</script>
```

It's all echo'd via PHP and such. data.php just has some basic stuff printed with PHP.

Comment: You should post some code, otherwise it's just a guessing game

Comment: Posted some sample code from the pages.

Comment: you're using jQuery, but you've hand rolled xmlhttp requests? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to load paid.php on index.php. Just move your setInterval code and add the DIV with id = "payment" to index.php.

If you want to keep it how it is now, you need to make sure the JS that is returned from cart.php is actually running. Also make sure you only have one DIV with id = "payment".

Comment: Oops. Renamed the php stuff in my code to make it less confusing and more generic.

I need the setInterval code within the catalog.php page because it passes another variable to data.php that isn't known until after catalog.php is loaded.

Comment: quick test, if you open index.php, can you see check your console to see if the page is calling data.php every second?

Comment: It is not. It does when I load only catalog.php, but not when called within index.php.

Comment: Ok so now we know the JS is not being called. Next just use $("#divstuff").load("data.php?data=somedata"); without the interval function and just see if it loads.

Comment: Oh, also try adding jquery <script src="jq.js"></script> to the index.php page.

Comment: Same result. Works from catalog.php directly, but not from the index page.

Comment: I added jQuery to the index page earlier. No results.

Comment: Ok last attempt. Try puting the code on catalog.php inside this $(document).ready(function(e) {       setInterval...   });

Comment: Does the other content from catalog.php show up on index.php?

Comment: Yes. Only the DIV does not update. The JS IS loaded onto the page, but seems to not do anything.

Comment: sorry, I can't figure it out. My last bit of advice will be to use this function on index.php https://api.jquery.com/load/, then setup a callback function with the right values to load data.php.